# Unexpected end of data when zipping files in python (using system command)

Tags: python, zip

I'm using the following code to zip a folder of logs `os.system(python -m zipfile -c /home/pi/Desktop/adb.zip /home/pi/Desktop/tests/logs_ADB)`. This successfully creates a zip file in the correct location, however when trying later to **extract** the files using 7-Zip, the error "Unexpected end of data" occurs (but files can still be extracted - files aren't corrupt). When trying to extract using Windows, the filesystem claims that the zip file is empty despite it having a size and despite all the files being visible when you open using 7-Zip.

This makes me think that the zip file doesn't close properly when it's being created. Is there any way to resolve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why use `os.system()` for this?

Comment: @AMC I chose to do this as it was more concise, would you recommend another method?